# How can I validate a form inside a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of items, every row has it's own "action" buttons. One of the actions is editing the record, the other one shows a list of related records (loaded dynamically via an Ajax call), and so on. When the modal opens, the respective ID for the record will be passed to the modal as well.

For each row, when user clicks on the button, a Bootstrap modal will appear, with respective content (as I mentioned, dynamically from the server). The issue is, I cannot validate the forms for edit nor related records. Here is the code snippet I used for building the recordset:

```
      <a href="#"><span class="openRecordsModalBtn" id="7">Records</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="openEditModalBtn" id="7">Edit</span></a>
```

Modal:

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit record</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="recordModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Releted records</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The content of the modal generates by ajax (it is a simple HTML form). Here is the Javascript I used for calling the Ajax script and pass record ID to the modal:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.openRecordsModalBtn').on('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.modal-body').load('/ajax/record.php?id=' + id, function(){
            $('#recordModal').modal({show:true});
        })
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.openEditModalBtn').on('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.modal-body').load('/ajax/edit.php?id=' + id, function(){
            $('#editModal').modal({show:true});
        })
    })
});
```

My guess is, by the time page loads, the form has not been generated yet. Therefore, validation cannot be done. How can I validate the form created by the Ajax call?

This is the validation function:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
FormValidation.formValidation(
    document.getElementById('edit-form'),
    {
        fields: {
            name: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please provide a name.'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
            bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap(),
            submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
            defaultSubmit: new FormValidation.plugins.DefaultSubmit(),
            icon: new FormValidation.plugins.Icon({
                valid: 'fa fa-check',
                invalid: 'fa fa-times',
                validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
            }),
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show html or form which you are loading into edit modal body?

Comment: as you are rendering the form using ajax. I will consider calling the function validate_form after you finished the render the form. avoid using DOMContentLoaded because the form doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing JQuery and javascript? You should only be using one `$(document).ready(function()`. I believe to make this work, you need to use event delegation. Haven't tested this but hopefully something like this will work for you. Substitute `document` with the closest static parent element of the modals.

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#recordModal', '#editModal', function(e) {
  FormValidation.formValidation(
    document.getElementById('edit-form'), {
      fields: {
        name: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please provide a name.'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
        bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap(),
        submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
        defaultSubmit: new FormValidation.plugins.DefaultSubmit(),
        icon: new FormValidation.plugins.Icon({
          valid: 'fa fa-check',
          invalid: 'fa fa-times',
          validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
        }),
      },
    });
});
```

This explains about the [modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).